# How to make Django use two different databases based on debug flag

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to use the simple SQLite database on my local environment and use a Postgresql database in production. How can I configure the settings file to know which database to use based on the value of `DEBUG`?

Comment: just use different settings files. one for debug with sqlite, another with production config.

Comment: If you try developing with sqlite your **implementation into Postgres will fail**. They are different databases having differing syntax in a great many cases and require different function/processes for others. In the long run it will be more trouble than it is worth. You best option download the Postgres version you will use in production and install it locally.

Comment: Andrey Nelubin how do I do that?

Comment: @Belayer I agree, except that this can be fixed by running automated test cases against Postgres, or by having a proper staging system with the production database system. People might develop against SQLite for convenience (file is easy to wipe, easy to share, ...).

Answer (score 7):

There are several options available:

1. Below is a very cheap solution. Django always selects the database called 'default'. You can assign it conditionally in `settings.py`:

   ```py
   DATABASES = {
       'dev': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
           'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
       },
       'production': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
           # ...
       },
   }

   DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES['dev' if DEBUG else 'production']
   ```
2. You can implement an alternate settings module called `settings_dev.py`. Configure database there and use the environment variable [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) to point to `yourapp.settings_dev`.
3. Implementing a custom database router. This is almost certainly overkill for many use-cases. See the Django documentation on [multiple database support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/).