# Django - How to create and migrate two tables for development and production on same database? (prefix in front when running as dev)

Tags: django, django-models, django-environ

I am trying to have two tables in one database like below based on development and production environment.

- development `dev_my_comments`
- production `my_comments`

I tried using environment variable while declaring table like below

```
class Data_Comments(models.Model):
    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        GENERAL = 0
        YELLOW = 1
        RED = 2
    ord_no = models.ForeignKey(Data_Import, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    strike_comment_type =  models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, default=0)
    strike_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='comments_user')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_comments' if settings.ENV_TYPE == 'PRO' else 'dev_my_comments'
        app_label = "my_app"
```

by using this option, make migrations just renames existing tables instead of creating new... (wanted to have both the tables and want to migrate changes on both tables)

is there something I am missing to make it work?

Comment: Good question. I was thinking about it but I don't find the answer. I know it's not the same but would you solve your problem using two different databases? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709408/how-to-make-django-use-two-different-databases-based-on-debug-flag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work... because Django will create migration files and the value for `db_table` will be assigned to `dev_my_comments`. And your production will have the `dev_my_comments` as your table name as well.

I've not seen this pattern for naming tables, is there any reason you have to share the DB but name the table differently between dev & prod?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a good idea.
Anyway you can pass db_table as a constant and django will use the variable for the migrations.

```
db_table = TABLE_NAME
```

note* you can't change it after running migrate tho.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution which is already mentioned in my question... in Flask there is an option 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()   

this will create if table not exits....
 .... do we have anything like this in Django??